# Why isn't "nth-of-type" working for my blog query loop?

Tags: html, css, query-builder

I've created a query loop to repeat blog posts but they all look the same. I want them the feature images to all have different sizes, border styles, padding etc. For the sake of simplicity, I'm just working with border radiuses for now.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing. The code is applied to "Blog Loop" and should be impacting "Post Image".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n2hy.jpg)

Here's the actual page for anyone who wants to look:
https://bohobrandingco.com.au/absolutes/

Here's my code:

```
.post-image:nth-of-type(1){
border-radius:500px;
}
.post-image:nth-of-type(2) {
border-radius:10%;
}
.post-image:nth-of-type(3) {
border-radius:0px;
}
.post-image:nth-of-type(4) {
border-radius:200px;
}
```

I'm trying to create an asymmetrical two-column blog page but all the repeating posts look the same. I need them to look different.

I've tried using "nth-of-type(1)" in every element to see if I'm putting it in the wrong place but nothing has worked.

Comment: The `nth-of-type` only applies to siblings withing the same parent element, and `.post-image` are under separate parents, so only the first selector `(1)` is applied repeatedly. Just a future note, you should include the appropriate sections of HTML in the question so that people can provide an answer to match your html

Comment: You will need to apply `nth-of-type` at the `"brxe-eedvaa brxe-container"` level

Comment: That's where it is already applied. I've also updated the code to apply only to the block surrounding the image, text, etc. So the blocks all share the same parent, "brxe-eedvaa brxe-container" and the code is still not working.They should all have different coloured borders and they don't.

Comment: Also, sorry for not including HTML. I can write basic HTML myself but am always hesitant about supplying it when it's written by a builder as I don't always understand what it's done.

Comment: You need to paste the block of HTML generated by the builder because it's pertinent to finding a suitable selector to match.  Anyway, `div.brxe-eedvaa:nth-child(1) .post-image`, `div.brxe-eedvaa:nth-child(2) .post-image` etc.

Comment: Similarly, you can also use nth-of-type: `div.brxe-eedvaa:nth-of-type(1) .post-image` etc.

Comment: Your code worked! I didn't include the "div" part but it worked! I really thought I included that class name at the start before but I must have done it wrong. Thank you so much!